# Is order (first, second, etc) a quality?

Tags: language

> No. Quantity is independent of quality. The number of items is not an
> attribute of an item.

I’m really sorry, but I only got an answer about quantity from the other stackexchanges. I really want to know whether **order** is quality or not.

Comment: No, because an object can be sometimes the first and sometimes the second; it is more a relation.

Comment: Not any arbitrary set can be ordered well like a strict google page sorting, order is intimately related with a famous self-evident axiom called AC (axiom of choice). In some math model we can discard this axiom, then order may not be always possible thus becomes neither a quantity nor a quality. In the most cases with AC such as ZFC, order is a type of quantity called ordinal thus it's definitely counted same as our usual type of quantity called number...

Comment: If you downvote posts, please give a reason.

Answer (score -1):

I appreciate your hard work for getting an answer to a question regarding an abstract idea.  So, let me share some of my ideas.

Order is not a quality. But in some cases, it may have some relation with quality.  Sometimes that quality may be unknown. Eg: The order of planets.  In other words, quality may determine order; but not always.  Sometimes a particular order can happen by accident.

If the objects are arranged in different order, we cannot say anything about their quality just by considering their order. I mean, any of its **characteristic or feature**.
That means, order does not necessarily imply quality.  In other words, order **is not** a quality.  If order can give quality (or is a quality), a different order must **always** increase or decrease any of its quality. But this never happens.

You can consider this also:  The position or order of (the parents') children never indicates their quality/ability.   Can we ever come to a conclusion that the first son is better/worse than the second and the third better/worse than the second?

So, IMHO, no need of a doubt about it.

Answer (score -1):

In physics, ordering is a quality.

Bosons can be in the same groundstate, making them interchangeable, fermions not & can't. Basically all of chemistry results from electrons being fermions, & protons not.

Entropy is another property of ordering, with profound implications for qualities, for dynamics.

We see emergent synergies, where a critical amount of something develops different behaviours, eg neurons in a brain.

> "number of items is not an attribute of an item."

There's a hidden premise here. That the item/s fully isolated. Thermal properties belong to a bulk, groundstates relate to group properties, neurons have organisational intelligence (eg convolutional neural networks that perform successive analysis). But the wider properties *don't belong to the item*, but to an assembly.